# Does reflection risk incoherence?

Tags: haskell, reflection, typeclass

The `reflection` package offers a class

```
class Reifies s a | s -> a where
  reflect :: proxy s -> a
```

and a function

```
reify :: a -> (forall s . Reifies s a => Proxy s -> r) -> r
```

Given only these, one could mess things up rather badly by giving, for example, the instance

```
instance Reifies s Int where
  reflect _ = 0
```

This would be bad because, for instance,

```
reify (1 :: Int) $ \p -> reflect p
```

could legitimately produce either 1 (via the usual reflection process) or 0 (by specializing the passed function before applying `reify`).

In reality, this particular exploit seems to be blocked by the inclusion of a few `Reifies` instances in `Data.Reflection`. The evil instance I described will be rejected as overlapping. If overlapping instances are enabled, I believe the specialization may be blocked by the uncertainty overlapping brings.

Still, I'm wondering if there's some way to expose this with a shady instance, perhaps with the help of GADTs or some such.

Answer (score 3):

I tentatively say it doesn't risk incoherence. After some tinkering, the best way I could come up with to hijack `reflect` used `INCOHERENT`, which is unsurprisingly sufficient to yield incoherence:

```
{-# LANGUAGE
  TypeFamilies, FlexibleInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses,
  ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Data.Constraint
import Data.Proxy
import Data.Reflection

instance {-# INCOHERENT #-} Reifies (s :: *) Int where
  reflect _ = 0

reflectThis :: forall (s :: *). Dict (Reifies s Int)
reflectThis = Dict

-- prints 0
main = print $
  reify (1 :: Int) $ \(p :: Proxy s) ->
   case reflectThis :: Dict (Reifies s Int) of
     Dict -> reflect p
```

Comment: Hmmm... I wonder if GHC could be tricked by using `SPECIALIZE` on a function ultimately passed to `reify`. I'm going to try that when I get home.